# Turtlebot- Find a map after building and saving it on android

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I run Make_a_Map application on android I succeeded to run everything including to save a map ( at least I have a massege), but where do I save it? What is map's location? On turtlebot's laptop or On my tablet?

Help me please because I cannot find it anywhere

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44432/turtlebot--find-a-map-after-building-and-saving-it-on-android/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maps live in and are accessed through the [map_store](http://ros.org/wiki/map_store) node, which is backed by a mongodb instance. The map_store node has some service calls you can make to extract maps, but they aren't documented.

Once you've made a map and loaded it with one of the android applications, you should be able to use the map_saver node in map_server to save your map to a file; take a look at the documentation for [map_saver](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server#map_saver)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2013-04-07**:
I found out that my problem is with mongodb instance. I have an error from rxconsole: " exited with exit code 100". what can be the cause? how can I fix this error?